# SSRS project, files structure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

my job is to develop and manage SSRS reports.

On the enterprise SSRS server i created directories to manage permissions for different groups of users. But VisualStudio SSRS project supports only flat representation of reports. It is rather unhandy to deploy them (and become worse when they have links to each other).

Creating multiple projects is incomplete solution because of cross-directory links. It will disable preview function in report designer.

So, question is: is this possible to have equal non-flat structure both in VS project and in publicated to the server reports?

Comment: Google for "deploy rdl with rs.exe" - rs.exe is a scripting utility you can use e.g. in a post build step in VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Geoff Hudik's method for now: http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2011/10/13/uploading-ssrs-reports-with-powershell.html

This is a PowerShell function that allows uploading multiple reports to ReportServer using the wcf interface, so publication can be automated.

Usage is as simple as:

```
UploadReports "report-server.domain.com" "c:\temp" "/TEST1/AppName"
```